# Need vba code to search multiple data in one worksheet

Tags: sql, excel, vba, ms-access

Hi I am looking for a vba code to search multiple data within one worksheet then populate the correspondence information to a new worksheet, here is example:

In a data sheet I have

```
Customer Number Customer Name   Invoice Date    Invoice Amount
1                ABC            4/17/2012       $5,000.00 
2                FGI            4/18/2012       $4,560.00 
3                NEC            4/19/2012       $687.00 
4                IEO            4/20/2012       $158.00 
5                PWO            4/21/2012       $1,549.00 
4                IEO            4/22/2012       $3,247.00 
1                ABC            4/23/2012       $1,590.00 
2                FGI            4/24/2012       $165.00 
3                NEC            4/25/2012       $158.00 
6                VCW            4/26/2012       $3,777.00
```

when I search the customer names:

```
ABC
FGI
NEC
IEO
PWO
```

it will show the result in a new worksheet like:

```
Customer Number Customer Name   Invoice Date    Invoice Amount
1                ABC            4/17/2012       $5,000.00 
1                ABC            4/23/2012       $1,590.00 
2                FGI            4/18/2012       $4,560.00
2                FGI            4/24/2012       $165.00 
3                NEC            4/19/2012       $687.00 
3                NEC            4/25/2012       $158.00 
4                IEO            4/20/2012       $158.00 
4                IEO            4/22/2012       $3,247.00 
5                PWO            4/21/2012       $1,549.00
```

Comment: Welcome to [so]. Please take a moment to read [ask] and [mcve] - SO is not a "please write code for me" site where you give specs and people give you free code. Go ahead, try things. When they break and you're stuck on a *specific* issue, you'll find SO in your research - and if you don't then you'll have a good question to ask =)

Answer (score 1):

[Data Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Eh5at.jpg)

[Search Result Sheet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rxkgB.jpg)

Name one sheet Data and another sheet Search Result. Do note the search column.

Sub Search()

```
 Dim i, j, newsheet_rownum
 newsheet_rownum = 2
 Sheets("Search Result").Range("A2:D65536").ClearContents

 For i = 2 To 65536
    If Len(Cells(i, 6)) = 0 Then
        Exit For
    End If

    For j = 2 To 65536

        If (Cells(i, 6) = Cells(j, 2)) Then
            Sheets("Search Result").Cells(newsheet_rownum, 1) = Sheets("Data").Cells(j, 1)
            Sheets("Search Result").Cells(newsheet_rownum, 2) = Sheets("Data").Cells(j, 2)
            Sheets("Search Result").Cells(newsheet_rownum, 3) = Sheets("Data").Cells(j, 3)
            Sheets("Search Result").Cells(newsheet_rownum, 4) = Sheets("Data").Cells(j, 4)
            newsheet_rownum = newsheet_rownum + 1
        End If

    Next j

 Next i
 MsgBox "Job Done"
```

End Sub